# ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(23,3): error TS1146: Declaration expected

Tags: angular

I've been trying to resolve this error for days and I don't know what to do anymore. I'm new with Angular and I don't know how things work yet. I'm stuck and I don't understand how to fix it. I've already installed and uninstalled several times the modules on their latest version.

**Error:**

```
Date: 2018-07-12T15:50:51.658Z - Hash: e52bb885c7cfcb67e69c - Time: 11159ms
3 unchanged chunks
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 5.74 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 3.14 MB [initial] [rendered]

WARNING in ./src/main.ts
8:41-50 "export 'AppModule' was not found in './app/app.module'
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled with warnings.
i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
 10% building modules 0/2 modules 2 active … lazy groupOptions: {} namespace objectERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(23,3): error TS1146:     Declaration expected.

Date: 2018-07-12T15:53:03.615Z - Hash: 8944712e4124fea4b527 - Time: 802ms
4 unchanged chunks
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 74.6 kB [initial] [rendered]

WARNING in ./src/main.ts
8:41-50 "export 'AppModule' was not found in './app/app.module'
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled with warnings.
i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...

Date: 2018-07-12T15:57:27.693Z - Hash: 8944712e4124fea4b527 - Time: 421ms
5 unchanged chunks

WARNING in ./src/main.ts
8:41-50 "export 'AppModule' was not found in './app/app.module'
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled with warnings.
ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(23,3): error TS1146: Declaration expected.
```

**My index.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <title>ConFusion</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

**App.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar'; 
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';


import 'hammerjs';

@NgModule({

  imports: [ 


    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    FlexLayoutModule

  ],

})
```

**App.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

**App.component.html**

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<mat-toolbar color="primary"> <span>Ristorante Con Fusion</span> </mat-toolbar>
```

**Styles.scss**

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';

// some basic resets 

body { 
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0; 
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; 

}
```

Comment: I'm going to give you the benefit of the doubt here.  This is at least a formed question and there appears to be enough detail that anyone with Angular experience could dive in and help you address.

Comment: If you haven't already, perhaps consider completing the official Angular Tutorial to learn the fundamental concepts. https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: Ok. I'm doing it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem! I'll leave the steps below in case anyone has the same problem:

**I deleted everything and re-installed Angular-cli globally:**

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

**Created conFusion project:**

```
ng new conFusion --style=scss
```

**In the conFusion project I installed:**

```
npm install @angular/material@latest --save
npm install @angular/cdk@latest --save
npm install --save @angular/animations@latest
npm install --save hammerjs@latest
```

**In the 'head' of index.html I added:**

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

**Then:**

```
npm install --save @angular/flex-layout@latest
```

**In app.module.ts:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar'; 
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';


import 'hammerjs';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
   imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    FlexLayoutModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**In the app.component.html I replaced with:**

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary"> <span>Ristorante Con Fusion</span> </mat-toolbar>
```

**In styles.scss:**

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';

// some basic resets 

body { 
 padding: 0; 
 margin: 0; 
 font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; 

}
```

With all that the app runs perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You need an export statement for your module:

```
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: I added export class AppModule {} to the app.module.ts but it doesn't work. Now it says: 'Error in No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing to add this line. Then only error occured.

```
export class AppModule {}
```

You are not added this line in `app.module.ts` file. Also in your `main.ts` file you are try to use this AppModule in boostrapping. Then only it shows errors.Once you added this line the error will be solve.

I hope you understand what you did mistake. For more reference go angular.io official website to start learn angular